# error message Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = 0) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using a code like

```
 df2<-df[1:3000,]

tail(df2)
df4<-(table(df2)>0)*1
dim(df4)
m.adj<-matrix(0,nc=1:5217,nr=5217)
for(i in 1:5215){
  for(j in (i+1):5216){
    m.adj[i,j]<-sum(df2[,i]*df2[,j])
  }
}
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = NA_integer_) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

it gives me an error( above) I am not able to find the solution for it .any suggestion will highly be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe in words what you are trying to do here.  We will be better able to help you then.

Comment: @ Andrie sir,I am trying to find the degree centrality of user in a crosstable consists of 0 and 1 ( 0 is for no comment on article and 1 is for comment on article , but before running the igraph package it gives me the error ,i hope I explain it well.

Answer (score 1):

This error tells you that the subscript you trying to get in `m.adj` is exceeding the size of this `matrix`.

The size of `m.adj` is 5217 x 1, because you defined it in this way: `m.adj<-matrix(0,nc=1:5217,nr=5217)` whereas it should be defined in this way:

```
m.adj<-matrix(0,nc=5217,nr=5217)
```

because the argument `nc` must be an integer and not an array of integers. Otherwise it takes the first element of the array. And here it is one.

Therefore, you just need to put in your code `m.adj<-matrix(0,nc=5217,nr=5217)`
 and it should work!

Comment: sir how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: Don't call me sir ;) Could you please post the result of `dim(df2)`?

Comment: OK. Thus my answer is wrong... See the update of my answer for the solution

Comment: the problem is the same is it was before :(

Comment: Yeah... because I made a mistake in my last sentence... You should put `m.adj<-matrix(0,nc=5217,nr=5217)`

Comment: now getting this message Error in df4[, j] : subscript out of bounds